# How to properly handle Exceptions in client thrown by a SOAP web service

Tags: spring-boot, soap

I am setting up a Client using Spring-boot in Java to access a soap endpoint (for testing purpose).What's the best approach to handle Exceptions? I want to handle SOAPFaultClientExceptions...

**I have already tried this:**
[How to Parse SoapFaultClientException in spring-ws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43329256/how-to-parse-soapfaultclientexception-in-spring-ws)

but it didn't work properly, as I couldn't call the `getValue()` method on `detail`

```
try {
        JAXBElement res = (JAXBElement) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(url, request);
        return (GetBankResponseType) res.getValue();
    }catch (SoapFaultClientException ex) {
        SoapFaultDetail soapFaultDetail = ex.getSoapFault().getFaultDetail(); // <soapFaultDetail> node
        // if there is no fault soapFaultDetail ...
        if (soapFaultDetail == null) {
            throw ex;
        }
        SoapFaultDetailElement detailElementChild = soapFaultDetail.getDetailEntries().next();
        Source detailSource = detailElementChild.getSource();
        Object detail = getWebServiceTemplate().getUnmarshaller().unmarshal(detailSource);
        JAXBElement source = (JAXBElement) detail;
        System.out.println("Text::"+source.getValue());
    }//catch other Exceptions...Which ones?
    return null;
}
```

Expected result is a handled Exception, (SOAPFaultClientException) or others... which get Thrown by the webservice when wrong parameters are passed. I don't find any suitable solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Configure [ClientInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/api/org/springframework/ws/client/support/interceptor/ClientInterceptor.html) or [FaultMessageResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/api/org/springframework/ws/client/core/FaultMessageResolver.html) to your WebServiceTemplate and do your error handling there.